# i want that ball on collision should start moving reverse direction. Right now my ball just stop at detecting the collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

```
public class moveBall : MonoBehaviour {

private const float SPEED = 5f;
private Vector3 direction;
private Vector3 inversedirection;
private float distance =0f;
private Vector3 lastPos;
private RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    direction = (new Vector3( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)).normalized;
    inversedirection = (new Vector3 (-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)).normalized;
    lastPos = transform.position;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.position += direction * SPEED * Time.deltaTime;

    lastPos = transform.position;
    Debug.DrawRay (transform.position, direction * 2,  Color.green);
    if (Physics.Raycast (transform.position, direction, out hit, 2)) {
                    Debug.Log ("Hit");
                    print (lastPos.x);
                    if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Plane") {
                            Destroy (this);
                    }
            }


}
}
```

Please help. If someone can suggest me how to proceed. I want that that ball collides the plane and the moves opposite direction.I am using Raycast to detect the collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Unity, so I'm not sure what `Destroy(this);` does (I can guess), but if you want the ball to bounce when you hit the plane, you need to change the direction of the ball instead of destroying the current object. So maybe something like

```
if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Plane") {
    direction = inversedirection;
    inversedirection = direction;
}
```

Or just drop the whole `inversedirection` variable and write

```
if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Plane")
    direction *= -1;
```

That said, this only works if the ball always travels perpendicular to the plane. Otherwise, you'll have to reflect the direction vector in the normal of the plane, rather than inverting the direction.